# ¿Cómo comunicar html y css en json para una extension de chrome?

Tags: html, css, json, chrome

Lo que intento es tener una extensión de chrome en json en la que, al darle click a un botón mostrado en html, se active o modifique código de css de la página actual.

Ejemplo: estoy en Google, le doy click al botón de la extensión y el fondo se vuelve negro.

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías agregar tu avance por favor?

Comment: @BetaM el caso es que no sé cómo pensarlo todo

Comment: Cualquier avance que lleves ayudaría mucho para de ahi partir